# Play video automatically when Modal is triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-modal

I have a modal. A video presentation in Modal. Modal triggered video is automatically auto play. The video will be turned off in a modal outdoor environment, the video should start automatically when the modal is turned on. But now it does not work as desired.

Where do you think I'm making a mistake? Thanks

```
<!-- Modal Trigger Button --> 
<div> <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#arcaVideoModal" href="#"></div>


<!-- Modal-->
    <div id="arcaVideoModal"  class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="arcaVideoModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                    <video id="video1" width="320" height="240" controls>
                        <source src="/Documents/arca-cm18.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                    </video>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#arcaVideoModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
            $('#video1')[0].play();
        })
        $('#arcaVideoModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
            $('#video1')[0].pause();
        })
        $(window).resize(function () {

            $('#arcaVideoModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
                $('#video1')[0].play();
            })
            $('#arcaVideoModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
                $('#video1')[0].pause();
            })
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: you are triggering pause on modal show and play on hide. That's your mistake

Comment: Show = play, hidden = pause .. I made the necessary corrections, I tried your sample code but the problem didn't improve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to this question. I share the solution below for my friends who may need them after me. **Good coding for everyone.** Thank you so much.

```
enter code here     <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        //Video play
        $("#btn_play").on("click", function () {
            var video = $('#video1')[0];
            video.play();
        });
    });

</script>

<script>
    $(document).on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
        var video = $('#video1')[0];
        video.pause();
    });
</script>
```

Play and pause feature to be triggered to be written in separate script tags. This is a solution to my problem. There may be different solution methods. We love different ideas :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btn_play").on("click", function(){
      $('#arcaVideoModal').modal("show")
    })
    $('#arcaVideoModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
        $('#video1')[0].play();
    });
    $('#arcaVideoModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
        $('#video1')[0].pause();
    });
    $(window).resize(function () {
        $('#arcaVideoModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
            $('#video1')[0].play();
        })
        $('#arcaVideoModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
            $('#video1')[0].pause();
        })
    });
});
```

You are making mistake as you are pausing video on modal.show and playing it on modal.hide

**For your reference:**

I have created a stackblitz for you

Url: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-v1nl51

Comment: Thanks for the reply Manj1790. Sorry, the video does not start playing when modal is turned on

Comment: You were pausing video on show and playing it on hide

Comment: Yeah. I want to stop the video when the modal closes. I want to start video when modal is turned on.That's what I wanted to do, man. I still haven't reached the solution.

Comment: The video in the example works, but the video does not close when it is closed. Works in the background.

Comment: But I have a problem. I wonder where I'm making a mistake. I still haven't detected that. I didn't want to write other libraries, they don't matter now. I have carousel.js, YandexMap.js, ajax.js and tooltip.js scripts. I have a few styles of library before the body. My application Bootstrap version 3.3.7 Jquery version : 3.2.1 Library Link : Body before <link href="/Content/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /> Body after <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script> –

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. This should work

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#arcaVideoModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
        $('#video1').play();
    })
    $('#arcaVideoModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
        $('#video1').pause();
    })

    $(window).resize(function () {

        $('#arcaVideoModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
            $('#video1').play();
        })
        $('#arcaVideoModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
            $('#video1').pause();
        })


    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Ashish. Sorry, the video does not start playing when modal is turned on.